# Reduction of columb names to get corrplot to work

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

Why does R change my colnames when I do the correlations?

I have 25 variables with long names. I want to make a corrplot on these 25 variables, but the plot dissapears/are corrupted (probably due to long names - I only see a red border line, when I use smaller dataset corrplot works)

I make a pivot in melt/cast:

```
dat.1 =melt(dat, id.vars = c("SECTOR1", "Dato"), measure.vars = c("spread"))

x<-cast (dat.1,  Dato ~ SECTOR1, mean,  value = "spread")
```

So i try to reduce the name length with abbreviate.

```
nam <-abbreviate (colnames(x),4)

colnames (x) <- nam
```

When executing:

```
cor(x)
```

R is using the old long names and the plot through

```
corrplot(cor(x), method ="circle")
```

Is still corrupted

Comment: I cannot replicate the same issue, please provide a reproducible example

Comment: i cannot replicate it either. When I do thos everything works fine:
ttt <- data.frame(cbind(longname=c(1,2,3,4,5), verylongname=c(5,4,3,2,1)))
colnames(ttt) <- abbreviate(colnames(ttt),2)
corrplot(cor(ttt), method = "circle")